# Change font size of Canvas without knowing font family

Tags: javascript, canvas

Is there a way to only change the font size of a canvas context without having to know/write the font family.

```
 var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

 ctx.font = '20px Arial'; //Need to speficy both size and family...
```

Note:

```
ctx.fontSize = '12px'; //doesn't exist so won't work...
ctx.style.fontSize = '20 px' //doesn't exist so won't work... 
                         //we are changing the ctx, not the canvas itself
```

Other note: I could do something like: detect where 'px' is, remove what's before 'px' and replace it by my font size. But I'd like something easier than that if possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update: (from comments) There is no way around specifying font. The Canvas' font is modeled after the short-hand version of font in CSS.

However, there is always a font set on the canvas (or a font *type*) so what you can do is to first extract the current font by using it like this:

```
var cFont = ctx.font;
```

Then replace size arguments and set it back (note that there might be a style parameter there as well).

A simple split for the sake of example:

```
var fontArgs = ctx.font.split(' ');
var newSize = '12px';
ctx.font = newSize + ' ' + fontArgs[fontArgs.length - 1]; /// using the last part
```

You will need support for style if needed (IIRC it comes first if used).
Notice that font-size is fourth parameter, so this will not work if you will have/not have font-variant(bold,italic,oblique), font-variant(normal, small-caps) and font-weight(bold etc).

Comment: You're doing what I've mentionned in my Other note:

Comment: @RainingChain I might be going blind, but where do you show this?

Comment: @RainingChain there is no way around specifying font. The Canvas' font is modeled after the short-hand version of font in CSS.

Comment: seems dumb that you can't specify the font props individually :(

Comment: This answer does not take into consideration font names that contain spaces like `sakkal majalla` or `Times New Roman` etc. Splitting by space will yield an array containing the font size plus as many words as the font name, each in an element

Answer (score 26):

Here is an easier and cleaner way of changing the font size that will work regardless if you are using font-variant or font-weight or not.

First some RegEx to match and return the current font size

```
const match = /(?<value>\d+\.?\d*)/;
```

Set an absolute size, assuming your new font size is 12px

```
ctx.font = ctx.font.replace(match, 12);
```

Set a relative size, increase by 5:

```
const newSize = parseFloat(ctx.font.match(match).groups.value + 5);
ctx.font = ctx.font.replace(match, newSize);
```

Working example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Match on digit at least once, optional decimal, and optional digits
// Named group `value`
const match = /(?<value>\d+\.?\d*)/;

const setFontSize = (size) => ctx.font = ctx.font.replace(match, size);

const adjustFontSize = (amount) => {
  const newSize = parseFloat(ctx.font.match(match).groups.value + amount);
  return ctx.font = ctx.font.replace(match, newSize);
}

// Default font is 12px sans-serif
console.log( setFontSize(18) );    // 18px sans-serif
console.log( adjustFontSize(2) );  // 20px sans-serif
console.log( adjustFontSize(-5) ); // 15px sans-serif
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: `replace` can take a function to substitute, you don't need to do a regex match twice...

Comment: Sometimes, it is necessary to use float instead of int. ctx.font = ctx.font.replace(/[0-9.]+px/, (parseFloat(ctx.font.match(/[0-9.]+px/)) + 2) + "px") can cover this situation.

Answer (score 2):

try this (using jquery):

```
    var span = $('<span/>').css('font', context.font).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('body').append(span);
    span[0].style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    span[0].style.fontSize = '12px';
    //add more style here.
    var font = span[0].style.font;
    span.remove();
    return font;
```

Comment: Good idea. No need to append to body nor use jQuery. `var span = document.createElement('span'); span.style.font = ctx.font; return span.style.fontSize;`

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner way to not worry about scraping every other parameter:

```
canvas.style.font = canvas.getContext("2d").font;
canvas.style.fontSize = newVal + "px";

canvas.getContext("2d").font = canvas.style.font;
```

Explanation:
As mentioned in the first answer, the canvas context will always have a font. So `canvas.getContext("2d").font` might return something like `"10px sans-serif"`. To not scrape this string we can use the Canvas DOM element (or any other element) to parse the full font spec and populate the other font fields. Which means that after setting:

```
canvas.style.font = "10px sans-serif";
canvas.style.fontSize = "26px";
```

the `canvas.style.font` will become `"26px sans-serif"`. We can then pass this font spec back to the canvas context.

Comment: You're not setting the new `fontSize` anywhere?

Comment: As mentioned in the first answer, the canvas context will always have a font. So `canvas.getContext("2d").font` might return something like `"10px sans-serif"`. To not scrape this string we can use the Canvas DOM element (or any other element) to parse the full font spec and populate the other font fields. Which means that after setting `canvas.style.fontSize = "26px";` the `canvas.style.font` will become `"26px sans-serif"`. We then feed this font spec back to the canvas context.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly answer your question, there is no way to change the font size of a canvas context without having to know/write the font family.