# How to change font size of canvas text

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have text on my loading screen in canvas but it's too small. I somehow can't find any resources on what the correct syntax is to change it.

I tried:

```
// examples of what i've tried

canvasContext.font(40); 
canvasContext.font(40 + 'px'); 
canvasContext.fontSize(40); 
canvasContext.fontSize(40 + 'px'); 
canvasContext.font = 40; 
canvasContext.font = 40 + 'px'; 
canvasContext.fontSize = 40; 
canvasContext.fontSize = 40 + 'px';
```

-

```
//my actual code

window.onload = function () {
    canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
}

function colorText(showWords, textX, textY, fillColor, fontSize) {

    //this works -----
    canvasContext.fillStyle = fillColor;
    canvasContext.fillText(showWords, textX, textY);

    //this doesn't ------
    canvasContext.fontSize = 40 + 'px';
}
```

Comment: ctx.font = "30px Arial";

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35626468/1377002

Comment: @Andy I looked for that but couldn't find :,( Thank you

Comment: @Andam I don't think so because that person knew that you needed a font-family and the proper syntax. I didn't

Comment: I know. Im not saying you did a wrong thing by posting this questuion but they are both the same thing. So we have to close it down in order to keep the stack clean of duplicate questions

Comment: @Andam Mk, I understand the concern. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
canvasContext.font= 40 + 'px';
```

for this:

```
canvasContext.font = `40px Verdana`;
```

**Note:**

Don't forget the property `canvasContext.font` should be setted before the `canvasContext.fillText`! But why? Because is in`fillText` function were the text is draw on the canvas. If the font property is set after, the text present on the canvas will not change, only if you draw it again.

**Follows a full working example:**

```js
//my actual code

var canvasContext;

window.onload = function () {
    canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');  
    colorText("Word", 30, 30, "white", "40px");
}

function colorText(showWords, textX, textY, fillColor, fontSize) {
    canvasContext.font = `${fontSize} Verdana`;
    canvasContext.fillStyle = fillColor;
    canvasContext.fillText(showWords, textX, textY);
   
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
```